# Protocol 'GetSignQuestions' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: swiftui, protocols

I have a protocol and two different Extensions. When PoliceSignalsView is opened, when I change the shared variable in SignQuestionProvider with PoliceSignQuestion(), it returns Police related questions. If I replaced it with TrafficSignQuestion() it would return me traffic related questions. This is working properly. However, there is a problem.

**Model 1:**

```
struct TrafficSignQuestion: Codable, Hashable {
    var trafficQuestions: [TrafficSign]?
}

enum TrafficSignSectionType: String, Codable, Hashable {
    case A = "A"
    case B = "B"
}

struct TrafficSign: Codable, Hashable {
    var id: Int?
    var image: String?
    var sections: [TrafficSignSectionType.RawValue : String]?
    var correct: String?
}
```

**Model 2:**

```
struct PoliceSignQuestion: Codable, Hashable {
    var policeQuestions: [PoliceSign]?
}

enum PoliceSignSectionType: String, Codable, Hashable {
    case A = "A"
    case B = "B"
    case C = "C"
}

struct PoliceSign: Codable, Hashable {
    var id: Int?
    var image: String?
    var sections: [PoliceSignSectionType.RawValue : String]?
    var correct: String?
}
```

**Protocol:**

```
protocol GetSignQuestions {
    func getQuestions(jsonService: JSONService) -> [Self]?
}

**SignQuestionProvider**

class SignQuestionProvider<T: Any>: ObservableObject {
    
    var shared: GetSignQuestions?
    @Published var allQuestions: T?
    
    func getQuestions() {
        let questions = shared?.getQuestions(jsonService: JSONService())
        allQuestions = questions as? T
        print("\(allQuestions)")
    }
}
```

**Extensions:**

```
extension PoliceSign: GetSignQuestions {
    func getQuestions(jsonService: JSONService) -> [PoliceSign]? {
        if let questions = jsonService.getQuestion(fileName: "policeQuestions", using: PoliceSignQuestion.self) {
            return questions.policeQuestions ?? []
        }
        return []
    }
}

extension TrafficSign: GetSignQuestions {
    func getQuestions(jsonService: JSONService) -> [TrafficSign]? {
        if let questions = jsonService.getQuestion(fileName: "trafficQuestions", using: TrafficSignQuestion.self) {
            return questions.trafficQuestions ?? []
        }
        return []
    }
}
```

**JSON Service:**

```
class JSONService: ObservableObject {
    
    func getQuestion<T: Codable>(fileName: String, using modelType: T.Type)  -> T? {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(modelType, from: data)
                return jsonData
            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

**PoliceSignalsView(FirstView):**

How can I transfer the data I get from here to QuestionCardView()? I couldn't make the Generic Binding build.

```
struct PoliceSignalsView: View {
    @StateObject var questionProvider = SignQuestionProvider<PoliceSignQuestion>()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            QuestionCardView()
        }
        .onAppear {
            questionProvider.shared = PoliceSignQuestion()

// When I change it to "TrafficSignQuestion", the TrafficSign function in the protocol works and returns TrafficSigns questions. I want to pass the result returned from here to QuestionCardView. How can I do that ?

            questionProvider.getQuestions()
        }
        .environmentObject(questionProvider)
    }
}
```

**SecondView(QuestionCardView):**

I don't want to see the policeQuestions property while showing the data from policeSignalsView here because it can be in trafficQuestions on this page. If I write it like this I get an error. how can i fix this problem?

```
struct QuestionCardView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var optionConfigure: OptionConfigure
    @EnvironmentObject var questionProvider: SignQuestionProvider<PoliceSignQuestion>
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           
            
            
            ForEach(questionProvider.allQuestions?.policeQuestions?.indices ?? 0..<0, id: \.self) { item in 
// here.. I don't want the "policeQuestions" property here. Because it should be a generic construct.
                Text("")
                    .animation(.spring())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, I don't want the policeQuestions property in ForEach on the QuestionCardView screen. I followed this way to remove it.

**Protocol:**

```
protocol GetSignQuestions {
    func getQuestions(jsonService: JSONService) -> [Self] // Array
}
```

**Extensions:**

```
extension PoliceSign: GetSignQuestions {
    
    func getQuestions(jsonService: JSONService) -> [PoliceSign] {
        if let questions = jsonService.getQuestion(fileName: "policeQuestions", using: PoliceSignQuestion.self) {
            return questions.policeQuestions ?? []
        }
        return []
    }
}

extension TrafficSign: GetSignQuestions {
    func getQuestions(jsonService: JSONService) -> [TrafficSign] {
        if let questions = jsonService.getQuestion(fileName: "trafficQuestions", using: TrafficSignQuestion.self) {
            return questions.trafficQuestions ?? []
        }
        return []
    }
}
```

**PoliceSignalsView:**

```
struct PoliceSignalsView: View {
    @StateObject var questionProvider = SignQuestionProvider<PoliceSign>()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            QuestionCardView()
        }
        .onAppear {
            questionProvider.shared = PoliceSign()
            questionProvider.getQuestions()
        }
        .environmentObject(questionProvider)
    }
}
```

When I make changes in this way, I get an error as in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reorganized some of the code and re-added the `Question` protocol from my previous answer to you. I've also slightly edited your model to make the `TrafficSign` and `PoliceSign` have non-optional `id` properties. Otherwise, using them in the `ForEach` is going to be problematic.

```
struct TrafficSignQuestion: Codable, Hashable {
    var trafficQuestions: [TrafficSign]?
}

enum TrafficSignSectionType: String, Codable, Hashable {
    case A = "A"
    case B = "B"
}

struct TrafficSign: Codable, Hashable, Question {
    var id: Int
    var image: String?
    var sections: [TrafficSignSectionType.RawValue : String]?
    var correct: String?
}

struct PoliceSignQuestion: Codable, Hashable {
    var policeQuestions: [PoliceSign]?
}

enum PoliceSignSectionType: String, Codable, Hashable {
    case A = "A"
    case B = "B"
    case C = "C"
}

struct PoliceSign: Codable, Hashable, Question {
    var id: Int
    var image: String?
    var sections: [PoliceSignSectionType.RawValue : String]?
    var correct: String?
}

protocol Question {
    var id: Int { get set }
    var image: String? { get set }
}

protocol GetSignQuestions {
    associatedtype QuestionType : Question
    func getQuestions(jsonService: JSONService) -> [QuestionType]?
}

class SignQuestionProvider<T: GetSignQuestions>: ObservableObject {
    @Published var allQuestions : [T.QuestionType] = []
    
    func getQuestions(getter: T) {
        if let questions = getter.getQuestions(jsonService: JSONService()) {
            self.allQuestions = questions
        }
        print("\(allQuestions)")
    }
}

struct PoliceSignGetter : GetSignQuestions {
    func getQuestions(jsonService: JSONService) -> [PoliceSign]? {
        if let questions = jsonService.getQuestion(fileName: "policeQuestions", using: PoliceSignQuestion.self) {
            return questions.policeQuestions ?? []
        }
        return []
    }
}

struct TrafficSignGetter: GetSignQuestions {
    func getQuestions(jsonService: JSONService) -> [TrafficSign]? {
        if let questions = jsonService.getQuestion(fileName: "trafficQuestions", using: TrafficSignQuestion.self) {
            return questions.trafficQuestions ?? []
        }
        return []
    }
}

class JSONService: ObservableObject {
    
    func getQuestion<T: Codable>(fileName: String, using modelType: T.Type)  -> T? {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(modelType, from: data)
                return jsonData
            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

struct PoliceSignalsView: View {
    @StateObject var questionProvider = SignQuestionProvider<PoliceSignGetter>()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            QuestionCardView<PoliceSign>(questions: questionProvider.allQuestions)
        }
        .onAppear {
            questionProvider.getQuestions(getter: PoliceSignGetter())
        }
    }
}

struct QuestionCardView<T: Question>: View {
    var questions: [Question]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(questions, id: \.id) { item in
                Text("")
                    .animation(.spring())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try when I go to home sir.

Comment: Great. Consider upvoting or re-accepting the other answer I gave you on the past question, since this really does seem to be a different scope and the other answer I gave worked for the question as asked on the last one.

Comment: In QuestionCardView() page, array returns empty in .onAppear function, but array is filled in .onDisappear function. When exiting the page, the data appears in the array. What is the reason ?

Comment: @UfukKöşker I don't see `onDisappear` anywhere in your code. `QuestionCardView` gets its array set after `onAppear` runs on its parent, so it makes sense that it would have an empty first value, but it should re-render one the array is set. Are you not seeing that happen?

Comment: Ok. Please consider up voting if you found the answer helpful. And, if you have a moment, please go back and re-review the last answer I provided you as well, that you un-accepted.